# Testing IOS app without connecting the device?

Tags: ios, xcode, device, provisioning

Me and a friend of mine are working on an iPad app remotely. I want him to be able to test the application but it has to be done remotely somehow. He's doing the graphics bits and doesnt know how to run Xcode and compile code.

I want to be able to send an app file that he can run on his device. I know it is possible, but can anyone point me to a guide of some sort?

I have added his device into my provisioning profile, but not sure what the next step is.

Many thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magic word is AdHoc, you can find more information about it in apple's developer portal.

And here is a how to create the App, that you can send with your ad hoc profile to your friend.
http://diaryofacodemonkey.ruprect.com/2011/03/18/ad-hoc-app-distribution-with-xcode-4/

Also you can take a look at https://testflightapp.com

Comment: Very nice guide in that link!

Comment: +1 for testflight. I use it to share builds with my clients all the time.

Answer (score 3):

The term you need to search for is ad-hoc distribution.

You will need to create a distribution profile in the provisioning portal and use this profile to sign your app when building for archive.

You can then archive your project and send an .ipa file via email which your partner can load onto his device using iTunes.